# Syntax for Instantiating Typealias variable with Closures

Tags: swift, syntax

I'm struggling to figure out/understand the correct syntax for instantiating a variable whose type is a typealias consisting of multiple closures.

I have the following closure typealiases

```
public typealias SuccessReturnBlock = (JSON?) -> Void
public typealias FailureBlock = (_ category: String, _ description: String) -> Void
```

With those 2 types, I am creating another typealias consisting of the combined responses

```
typealias completionBlock = (@escaping SuccessReturnBlock, @escaping FailureBlock)->Void
```

Now I want to try to have a class variable which is of typealias `completionBlock`, so I attempted this:

```
var completionReturnBlock: completionBlock = { (success, failure) in
    success(response)
}
```

I know that the above returns error of unresolved identifier because I haven't defined "response" anywhere within the declaration, so I tried to put something together like this:

```
var completionReturnBlock: completionBlock = { success: { (response) in

    }, failure in {

    }
}
```

But this isn't correct and throws "Contextual type for closure argument expects 2 arguments.  How would I go about writing the correct declaration/instantiation for `completionBlock`?

Comment: What do you mean "*the correct declaration/instantiation*"? What do you want it to do? Where is `response` supposed to come from?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the second example?  `completionBlock` is a closure which expects two arguments to be passed to it (and those two arguments are themselves closures).  Did you intend for `completionBlock` to be a tuple containing two closures?

Comment: I'm hoping to set `completionReturnBlock` to a callback from other functions. `response` would come from an async web call.  For a block that doesn't expect response, I can do something like `var completion: completionBlockNoReturn = { (success, failure) in
        success()
    }`